# How to assign unique value in hidden fields in a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post, hidden-field

So my question is this:
I am doing a foreach loop, and it generates a link list. Each link is having JavaScript in it, which submits the form. I want to, however, attached to EACH link a variable so that I can get the $_POST variable to see WHICH link has been clicked.

I tried a foreach loop and then something like:

```
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    ?>
    <div class="containerbla">
        <form>
            <h3><a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('matchesform').submit(); return false;"><?php echo $match->name?></a></h3>
            <?php echo $match->id; ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="matchid" value="<?php echo $match->id; ?>">
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

It shows the correct user name list and the correct user ID's right below. But when I click on the user, I always get the LATEST user Id in the hidden field submitted to my view-messages php.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Use an array: `<input type="hidden" name="matchid[]" value="<?php echo $match->id" ?>">`

Comment: Where is this 'matchesform' you are submitting?  It's not in this example, the forms you're creating programatically do not have an id, so their values are not the ones being submitted when you click.

Comment: @RobbieAverill: I tried but how does that help in actually retrieving the array / the value that got clicked? I tried $_POST['matchid'][0] and I still get the same result as aabove

Comment: I see - I suggest you take the javascript handler out of the HTML and define it separately. Add a data attribute to the anchor with the ID in it, and append that to the dataset before you post the data.

Comment: He is creating an input the reason it's not getting submitted is because the input is in the wrong form. For it to work you have to append the input to the correct form, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($matches as $key=>$match) { ?>

                <div class="containerbla">
                    <form>
                        <h3><a href="javascript:{}" onclick="var poop = document.getElementById('matchesform'); poop.insertAdjacentHTML('<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"poop\" value=\"<?php echo $key; ?>\"/>'); poop.submit(); return false;"><?php echo $match->name?></a></h3>
                        <?php echo $match->id; ?>
                        <input type="hidden" name="matchid" value="<?php echo $match->id; ?>">
                    </form>
                </div>
            <?php
            }
```

Then you will be able to get the index using `$matches[$_POST['poop']];`

**I see that you are creating a new input already, but you are not putting it in the correct form, that is why it isn't getting submitted.**

Comment: ah, i wasn't paying attention

Comment: whoever downvoted-- i might not have been paying attention but it was still the right answer :P

Comment: I +1'd you to balance it back out before. This does function, not sure why the downvote.

Comment: Thanks Pamblam for the response, will try it as soon as I get home.
As I want to become a good coder, can you explain WHY the code I posted don't work and why I needed to code it the way you suggested
What is the logic there, how can I understand the concept?

Comment: @FlashNewbie - What I changed was in your `onclick` attribute. The code I added creates an invisible input and puts it in the correct form before submitting the form. Your current code creates a new input with raw html and just drops it onto the page where it is. For this to work you can't just drop the input wherever you want, you have to drop the input into the form tha tis being submitted.